# How to re-install GCC 4.9.2 after installation

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, mingw, package

I am setting up Eclipse CDT for C++ and I installed the GCC compiler from equation.com. I installed it and the code wasn't updating so i decided to re-install. I deleted the MinGW folder and tried to run the installer again and now getting an error from the installer "System cannot find the file specified".

Also any help on uninstalling Code::Blocks as they are the same category of packages without magic uninstalling would be great.

Comment: Install CCleaner and clean your PC from broken uninstallers. Never delete folders and its contents that were created with installers.